# Strange page loading

Tags: html, css, pageload

The problem that I have, it´s that after going from section to section (after the page it´s loaded completely) the page does a strange load that kind of "jumps" the page when you load it, it´s something quickly but you can notice it and it´s annoying, like the whole wrapper jumps to load... What is wrong with it?

thanks

Comment: Can you tell us which browsers/versions are causing the issue? Chrome seemed to work other than each page asking if I wanted to translate, which pushed the content down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add some height for your top panel with logo, if it's that what u have on mind... that what i'v see and what is jumping :)

smth like that:

```
header #header_logo {
   width: 122px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding-top: 25px;
   height: 108px;
   position: relative;
}
```

but other things look fine

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the header is loading just a bit slower then the rest of the page. You can solve this issue by giving the header fixed height in your css

change the following in your css:

`header {position: relative;
}`

in

`header {position: relative; height: 200px;
}`

I didn't test this and I don't know if 200px is the correct height.